# Recommendations for automatic computer inventory

Tags: windows

For someone looking after a small 50 Windows PC network (Mainly XP - some Vista), are there any tools that can do an automatic inventory of the network e.g.

- OS
- Memory size
- Hard drive type and size
- Serial numbers
- Monitor type

etc.

At the moment, someone has to go from PC to PC writing all this stuff down.

Answer (score 4):

I have heard great things about [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/). Its big features are:

- creating an inventory of PCs and their installed software - Windows, Mac, Linux
- creating an inventory of routers, printers, and anything IP based.
- help desk ticketing
- network monitoring
- nice reporting

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of solutions (just [google "computer inventory"](http://www.google.com/search?q=computer%20inventory)), but the one I know of is [OCS Inventory NG](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/), although depending on your needs you may want to look for something a bit more friendly, as this open source project is somewhat complex.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb977556.aspx?SA_CE=NOT-MAP-BLOG-MAPBLOG-20081117) might be the tool for you.

Answer (score 1):

[CPU-z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) has a command line function that will write thing about the computer to a html file. That will give you memory and CPU type/speed. I believe the software [Everest](http://www.lavalys.com/news.php?article=57&selcat=PN&lang=en) can do the same for most of the other things you're looking for, except perhaps monitor type.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your PC manufacturer.  Most of the business ones have their own free inventory software that you can use.  Even if you just have one of these computers, grab the software to see if it meets your needs, and it might discover other PC brands too.  (Hint, hint.)

- Dell has [OpenManage](http://www1.us.dell.com/content/topics/global.aspx/sitelets/solutions/management/openmanage?c=us&cs=555&l=en&s=biz&redirect=1)
- HP has [System Insight Manager](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/hpsim/index.html), which also discovers & manages your servers & printers
- IBM has [IBM Director](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/management/director/)

The basic version is free, and then they resell software & services to sit atop these and provide more value.  They do stuff like remote control, software distribution, yadda yadda yadda.  Dell and HP's ones have web consoles with database back ends, which make it easier to roll your own reports too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on an Active Directory domain you can very quickly develop a Windows PowerShell script to do it all remotely via WMI queries.  If I could post a link, I would link you to a copy of the script I wrote.

Apart from writing a script there is the Microsoft Server Center stuff

Answer (score -1):

Our tool is Admin Arsenal. It does require your environment to be managed via Active Directory. www.AdminArsenal.com