# Network Inventory Software

Tags: networking

I would like opinions on network inventory software for a medium sized financial business.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail to the question? What platforms do you need to inventory? Do you just want inventory, or do you want configuration management and provisioning as well?

Comment: needs more detail but is probably OK as-is until a better version of this is asked

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for network, server, pc, and software inventory check out [spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com).

Great product. I have used it on both small and medium sized networks.  And did I mention it is **free**

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it's been covered here:

[Recommendations for automatic computer inventory](https://serverfault.com/questions/1760/recommendations-for-automatic-computer-inventory)

Lots of great answers there. Hope it satisfies your needs!

Answer (score 2):

I recently started using  OCS Inventory and find it quite useful.  The agent on the client regularly updates the central server, so its install and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at purely *network* inventory (routers, switches, firewalls etc), then [Opsware NAS](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-271-273%5E14681_4000_100__) and [Voyence](http://www.voyence.com/products/VoyenceControlNG.shtml) are two possible candidates. Both perform automated discovery, configuration management/backup and allow centralised configuration deployment.

I've not used it personally, but my understanding is that Voyence also has some nice features in terms of new device provisioning: i.e. you can define a set of best practise configuration, with some parameterised details like hostname, addressing etc and it will automatically provision a new device via a console connection.

If you are looking at more general inventory systems for everything (servers, desktops, network), then [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) does appear to meet the needs of most users in small/medium sized businesses.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for network devices you could get what you wanted with OpenView.

If you're looking for server and desktop inventory there a ton of choices including Tivoli Provisioning Manager (IBM), UniCenter (CA), or System Center (Microsoft). Of course those are on the expensive end.

We use Admin Arsenal (our product). It has a strong focus on inventory collection, as well as other system management tasks.

www.AdminArsenal.com

Answer (score 0):

Hardware Inventory - is a free program for getting hardware and software information from all computers in your network. Home page: [Hardware Inventory](http://hardwareinventory.net)