# Check softwares on all computers on a network

Tags: networking, active-directory, domain, domain-controller

i recently started a new job as IT and i'm kind of newbie at network management.
So i am asked to prepare an inventory list of all computers. Operating system info, Office Version info, Basic hardware info (RAM, CPU, HDD), Kaspersky and Skype versions if possible etc.

Is it possible to learn those kind of information trough network? O do i have to visit all computers one by one?
(I have admin privileges on domain)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq). [Product, service, or learning material recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa) are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: That is kinda awkward because if i will not learn how-to, or will not ask problem and get advices from other experts, why is this place exist? That is my first question on serverfault but not first in stackexchange. I think you simply got my question wrong. 3rd party or not i wanted to get knowledge since i'm newbie at network managements. Anyway, thanks for pointing that out @kce.

Comment: You're asking what product you can use to do this. That really matches what kce said is off-topic here. I'd suggest that you start simply googling "how to find out what's installed on remote computer". Then, if you have specific questions about how to handle the implementation you choose, ask away - that's far more likely to be on topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommendations for automatic computer inventory](http://serverfault.com/questions/1760/recommendations-for-automatic-computer-inventory)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do network inventories. There are many packages available both commercial/proprietary and free/open-source. lansweeper and spiceworks are 2 fairly general purpose and popular solutions. You'll need to evaluate the available options for your own needs.

Your question is quite broad, so I can't really give you a better answer than a broad "yes you can do it".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So since "I can" may i ask how? Do you know any free/open-source softwares for this?